# Thymeleaf form - how to pass a value for model attribute from one controller method to another one

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, logging, spring-data, thymeleaf

I'm struggling with adding products into product table for a specific user, whiich is logged via log method. The issue is that the attribue userLogin loses his value and is not equal to the user who logged into. So the actual value for attribute userLogin in addProduct method is null, hence there is an exception.

```
   @RequestMapping("/home")
  public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    model.addAttribute("userLogin", new Customer());
    return "register";
  }

  @PostMapping("/save")
  public String save(@ModelAttribute(value = "customer") @Valid Customer customer, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      throw new NotValidInputException();
    }
    if (customerService.checkIfCustomerIsInDb(customer)) {
      throw new CustomerAlreadyExists();
    }
    customerService.saveCustomerIntoDb(customer);
    return "saved";
  }


  @ExceptionHandler(NotValidInputException.class)
  public String notValidInputExceptionHandler() {
    return "databaseError";
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(CustomerAlreadyExists.class)
  public String customerAlreadyInDbHandler() {
    return "customerError";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/log")
  public String login(Model model, @ModelAttribute(name = "userLogin") Customer customerFromLoginForm) {

    if (Objects.isNull(customerService.getUserByLoggingDetails(customerFromLoginForm))) {
      return "userNotFound";
    }
    model.addAttribute("product", new Product());

    return "logged";
  }

  @PostMapping(value = "/addProduct")
  public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("userLogin") Customer customerFromLoginForm, @ModelAttribute(value = "product") Product product) {

    // customer is null
    customerFromLoginForm = customerService.findCustomerById(customerFromLoginForm.getId());
    product.setCustomer(customerFromLoginForm);
    customerFromLoginForm.setProducts(Arrays.asList(product));
    productService.addProduct(product);

    return "logged";
  }
```

The form in logged. html

```
<form th:method="post" th:action="@{addProduct}" th:object="${product}">
    <input type ="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Name" /><br />
    <input type ="text" th:field="*{category}" placeholder="Category" /><br />
    <input type="number"  th:field="*{price}"  placeholder="Price" /><br />
    <input style="text-align: center" type="submit" value="Add Product" /> </form>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Not able to pass model Attribute passed from controller to thymeleaf html back to another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271521/not-able-to-pass-model-attribute-passed-from-controller-to-thymeleaf-html-back-t) .
In general, I would use a hidden input for it, e.g:

```
<input type ="hidden" th:name="userLogin" th:value="${userLogin}" />
```

Then your controller method should get it. Let me know if this helps.